# tidyr spread values values from two columns (and rename columns)

Tags: r, dplyr, spread

I'm trying to build on code from [R - tidyr - mutate and spread multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993552/r-tidyr-mutate-and-spread-multiple-columns), I'm sorry if this is redundant with other posts and would be grateful to be pointed to those posts if they're out there!

```
example <- data.frame(category = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
                      value1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                      value2 = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90))

  category value1 value2
1        a      1     10
2        b      2     20
3        c      3     30
4        a      4     40
5        b      5     50
6        c      6     60
7        a      7     70
8        b      8     80
9        c      9     90
```

I understand how to pivot this to get the values from either `value1` or `value2`

```
example %>% 
spread(category, value1)
```

```
  value2  a  b  c
1     10  1 NA NA
2     20 NA  2 NA
3     30 NA NA  3
4     40  4 NA NA
5     50 NA  5 NA
6     60 NA NA  6
7     70  7 NA NA
8     80 NA  8 NA
9     90 NA NA  9
```

But I'd like to

1. mutate the names of the category column to reflect the 1 and 2 values, so there's two columns for each category

   2. populate the column values based on `values_from` = `value1` or `value2`

```
a_v1  a_v2  b_v1  b_v2  c_v1  c_v2
1     10    2     20    3     30
4     40    5     50    6     60
7     70    8     80    9     90
```

I realize my desired output will result in more rows with NAs like in the spread above but that's okay!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
example %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = category,
              values_from = c(value1, value2)) %>% 
  unnest()
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `pivot_wider` after creating a sequence column by 'category'.  As `pivot_wider` can take multiple `value_from` columns pass it as vector, either quoted or unquoted

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
example %>% 
    group_by(category) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = category, values_from = c(value1, value2))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#     rn value1_a value1_b value1_c value2_a value2_b value2_c
#  <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     1        1        2        3       10       20       30
#2     2        4        5        6       40       50       60
#3     3        7        8        9       70       80       90
```